# I Can't Get Ruby on Rails + Passenger + Apache to Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, apache-2.2

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't get Ruby on Rails to work on my Apache server.  I'm using Phusion Passenger (mod_rails, mod_rack) for app deployment.  Here is my RoR-specific configuration code in my website's Apache configuration file:

```
Alias /rails /var/www/syyborg.com/ruby/blog/public
<Directory /var/www/syyborg.com/ruby/blog/public>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
</Directory>
RailsBaseURI /rails
```

Again, I really have very little knowledge of this kind of thing; I have never set up a server from scratch before.  Anyways, my rails app, as you can see, is located at `/var/www/syyborg.com/ruby/blog/`.  I am trying to access it from `http://[my domain, syyborg.com]/rails`.  However, when I try to load the site, I get a "403 Forbidden" error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide further details if they are required.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you install Ruby, do you have the proper versions? If you installed it manually, I'd install it with [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) instead. This makes ruby and ruby on rails development a LOT simpler and according to your errors it does not seem to be set up properly.

Comment: @Jeff Ok, I'll have to try that. I used the command `apt-get install ruby ruby-dev libreadline-ruby libopenssl-ruby ri rdoc irb libhtml-template-perl psmisc -y` to install Ruby and its dependencies, then `cd /root; wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.7.2.tgz; tar xzvf rubygems-1.7.2.tgz; cd rubygems-1.7.2; ruby setup.rb` to install Ruby Gems, and `gem install rails` to install RoR.

Answer (score 1):

If mod_rails is properly installed & loaded, the only configuration you *need* in apache is to point the document root to the public folder.  mod_rails is smart enough to realize where the rest comes from.  in apache: the <Directory> statement refers to the physical file location rather than the perceived path.   This should *also* be your public folder for your rails app.

i.e.

```
<Directory /var/www/syyborg.com/ruby/blog/public>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
</Directory>
```

and your RailsBaseURI should be the path you're looking to use.

i.e.

```
RailsBaseURI "/rails"
```

Your alias statement looks fine.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, I got the same error as before...

Comment: did you "reload" apache or "restart" it?  Passenger sometimes gets quirky if you don't do a restart.  I have this configuration setup in production environments with 0 problems... with only one difference.  I also explicitly specify "RailsEnv production" in the <Directory> statement.

Comment: Yes, I did reload apache (through `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2`), and also tried declaring `RailsEnv production`.  Both returned the same error I've been encountering.

Comment: by restart.... I meant `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`   ...not reload.  Also, check permissions/ownership of the files.  It may not hurt to add a `PassengerRoot /var/www/syyborg.com/ruby/blog` entry either

Comment: I executed `sudo etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and nothing changed.  Then, I `chmod`ed the Rails app folder so that any user could read and write to it.  Now, instead of showing the Passenger error, it shows a "403 Forbidden" error.

Comment: do you use RVM or some other thingy like that ? If yes then you might be missing some important configuration bit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like mod_rails is not installed. Assuming that you have this:

```
gem install passenger
```

and

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Try to see if you can start passenger by itself like this:

```
cd /path/to/your/webapp
passenger start
```

Answer (score 0):

Passenger uses some filesystem magic to find the actual Rails apps. All its actions are based of the `DocumentRoot` of your virtual host.

Basically, passenger needs two configuration settings set:

1. It needs to know which *URL path* should be a rails app. This is done by setting the `RailsBaseURI` value in your Apache config.
2. It needs to know where the Rails application is located in the filesystem. Here it uses a rather special approach. Namely a symlink pointing to the public directory of your rails app (not the `RAILS_ROOT`). This symlink needs to be inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory.

So assuming your `DocumentRoot` is `/srv/www`, you need to create the following symlink:

```
ln -s /var/www/syyborg.com/ruby/blog/public /srv/www/rails
```

Note that it is considered good practice to NOT put your rails app inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Also, Passenger does not support the VirtualDocumentRoot module currently.

For more information, refer to the respective section of the [Passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri).